# Debug Next.js App with VSCode in NX monorepo

Tags: next.js, monorepo, nx-workspace

I'm currently trying to debug a **Next.js Application** inside a **NX monorepo**.

I have enabled the `Auto Attach` setting in VSCode's *User Settings*.

When I start the Application using the serve command, I can see output in the Debug Console and also print out the current process by typing `process` or `console.log(process)` into the *Debug Console*.

[image: VSCode Debug Console Output]

However, I cannot set any breakpoints in the server side code, for example in `getServerSideProps`.

I checked [Next.js Debugging Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging) for the missing pieces, and tried setting the `NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect'` in my Next.js Application via .env file.

Update: Seems like it's a [missing feature on NX](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4154).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working, thanks to the information from [this Pull Request](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4154).

#### .vscode/launch.json

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "resolveSourceMapLocations": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "!**/node_modules/**"],
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "name-of-the-app – Server",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "nx",
        "run",
        "name-of-the-app:serve",
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register",
        "-r",
        "tsconfig-paths/register"
      ],
      "outputCapture": "std",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "env": {
        "TS_NODE_IGNORE": "false",
        "TS_NODE_PROJECT": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/name-of-the-app/tsconfig.json"
      },
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/name-of-the-app/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: I'm using `yarn`. You might have to replace it with `npm` instead.

Comment: I'm getting this error, any ideas? 

`>  NX   'r' is not found in schema`